# reading 2nd line's 3rd word using batch commands

Tags: batch-file

i have a text file whose specific 3rd word of the 2nd line has to be extracted and written in another file 
for example:

```
line1: ELEMENT * CHEKDOUT 
line2: ELEMENT * ABC
line3: ELEMENT * \dir
```

in the above file.. 'ABC' has to be extracted and written into another file, say temp.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
<file.txt ( set /p "line=" & set /p "line=" )
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ("%line%") do echo %%a>temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As batch lines:

```
set "word="
for /f "skip=1okens=3" %%w in (yourtextfilename) do if not defined word set "word=%%w"
```

or

```
for /f "skip=1okens=3" %%w in (yourtextfilename) do set "word=%%w"&goto nextcmd
:nextcmd
```

The word would be inaccessible as `%word%`.

If you want just the word in the new file

```
for /f "skip=1okens=3" %%w in (yourtextfilename) do >newfilename echo(%%w&goto nextcmd
:nextcmd
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use an usually ignored feature of `setx` command that is fully explained at [Using SETX command to get tokens from a file](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5083). For example:

```
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('"setx /F filename.txt dummyVar /A 1,2"') do set "var=%%a" & goto continue
:continue
echo %var:~0,-1% > temp.txt
```

Note that lines and tokens in `setx /A` command are numbered from zero. Perhaps you need to adjust the "tokens=3" value in the `for` command; this is correct for Spanish version. You may execute the `setx` command alone to check it. For example:

```
C:\> type test.txt
ELEMENT * CHEKDOUT
ELEMENT * ABC
ELEMENT * \dir

C:\> test

C:\> type temp.txt
ABC

C:\> setx /F test.txt dummyVar /A 1,2

Valor extraído: ABC.

CORRECTO: se guardó el valor especificado.
```